# How to Wait Page Loading before Getting an Element?

Tags: java, selenium

This is not a duplicate since I have already read other questions relating to this but it didn't give me the answer I am looking for.

I am using Selenium for UI automation in Java.

My code is like this:

```
WebDriver driver;
public MyClass()
    {
        UIEvents auto = new UIEvents();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("my URL");

        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver, auto);
        waitForPageLoad();
        loginPage.setEmail("aaa@aa.a");
        loginPage.setPassword("1234");
        loginPage.clickLogin();
    }



    public void waitForPageLoad() 
    {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        final boolean response = js.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");

        if(response == false)
        {
            waitForPageLoad();
        }
}
```

This will still give me an error because it is searching for the element that still not existing.

Answer (score 2):

You also can wait until the desired element is present, visible, clickable,...

```
waitFor(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("yourMailInputId")));
```

Comment: What if the element of the said id didn't exist in the first place? Will this wait forever?

Comment: @ShizukaMasuda No, selenium driver have a property, "timeout" and will wait the default value, i think are 6-10 seconds, and if cant find it will throw and exception. But you should use elements you know are in the page, or should be, then if doesn't appears you know something wrong happened in your page

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot. But try changing "equals" to "equalsIgnoreCase".

```
final boolean response = js.executeScript("return document.readyState").equalsIgnoreCase("complete");
```

Comment: I can see during the debugging that the response changes to true when the page is done loading. My problem is occurring when I run my app.

Comment: Moreover, there is no equalsIgnoreCase in executeScript().

Comment: Sorry, I added .toString() --->  js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("complete");

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver_;

public void waitForPageLoad() {

    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver_, 30);
    wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            System.out.println("Current Window State       : "
                + String.valueOf(((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState")));
            return String
                .valueOf(((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState"))
                .equals("complete");
        }
    });
}
```